# Unexpected result when using toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jquery this code did'nt work Properly:

```
$('input').blur( function(){
       var prePayment = $('input').val();
       alert(prePayment.toLocaleString());
})
```

but when i type any number then blur from input did'nt show for example 9,000 , and show just 9000!
somwhere in my code that's worked but there is'nt worked!
what can i do 'toLocaleString()' working?

Comment: What is the `typeof prePayment`?  https://jsfiddle.net/ek7fvbzd/

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: Maybe you need quotes arount `input`? Or Is `input` a variable referencing a dom input element?

Comment: @BryanElliott `input` is the element/selector string they are binding the blur event to.  Verify first line.

Comment: the toLocalString() dont work!!! i wrote other things in my project true, just that function dont work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i typed a number in input, the string value is saved in prePayment like this '9000' and cause toLocalString did'nt work, so i wrote this code:

```
    $('input').blur( function(){
         var prePayment = parseInt($('input').val());
         alert(prePayment.toLocaleString());
    })
```

and done!!